# PHP & MySQL updating records, but page display not showing new data

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks for the help guys, it now redirects to winner.php but does not update the DB...

here is what I have now:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE depot = 'plainview'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if( isset($_POST['Submit'])){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql1 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET 

    available='{$_POST['available'][$i]}', 
    rent='{$_POST['rent'][$i]}', 
    corp_ready='{$_POST['corp_ready'][$i]}', 
    down='{$_POST['down'][$i]}', 
    gfs='{$_POST['gfs'][$i]}',
    dateTime = NOW()  

WHERE id='$id[$i]'"; 


$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
}
}


if($result1){
header("location: winner.php");
}
mysql_close();
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function mm_jumpmenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
//-->
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <p>Plainview, North East Region</p>
    <p>Select a different region: <select onchange="mm_jumpmenu('parent',this,0)" name="lostlist">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Your Depot</option>
                <option value="plainview.php">Plainview</option>
                <option value="worcrester.php">Worcrester</option>

                </select></p>
</div><Br />

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Available</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Rent</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Corp Ready</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Down</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>GFS</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="left"><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>

<td align="left"><?php echo $rows['product']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input name="available[]" type="text" id="available" value="<?php echo $rows['available']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="rent[]" type="text" id="rent" value="<?php echo $rows['rent']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="corp_ready[]" type="text" id="corp_ready" value="<?php echo $rows['corp_ready']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="down[]" type="text" id="down" value="<?php echo $rows['down']; ?>" size="5" /></td>
<td align="center"><input name="gfs[]" type="text" id="gfs" value="<?php echo $rows['gfs']; ?>" size="5"></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

I do realize this is hacked together, I am just starting to learn PHP...slowly...

thanks for the help!

Comment: `mm_jumpmenu()` Ah, nostalgia... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add on what **BraedenP** already wrote:

- it should be `if( isset($_POST['Submit'])){`
- your code is wide open for SQL injections

Comment: It sounds like the OP is fairly new to PHP development.  Some links on what SQL injection is and how to prevent it would probably be well-received.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here...

Firstly, to redirect the page, you actually need to send a header; right now you're just setting a $redirect variable. You will need to replace the line:

```
$redirect = "winner.php";
```

with:

```
header("location: winner.php");
```

Secondly, you cannot redirect the page after you have already written content to it, because writing content finalizes the headers sent back to the browser. The redirect will need to happen at the top of the page with the rest of your code.

After changing the line above, you should move all of the PHP that is below your table to the end of the stuff at the top of the page. After you do that, it should all work fine.

Comment: The redirect works, but now the DB does not update with new data...I edited my original question to show what I have so far.

Comment: Hmm... The code looks fine now. Perhaps $_POST['Submit'] isn't set, so it's not entering the query loop at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rearrange your code.

```
<?php

  // 1. Update if POST contains data

  // 2. query database here

  // 3. output result

?>
```

That way you don't need any redirect, because if you change something, you do it before you read the database again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing:
        WHERE id='$id[$i]'"
to this:
        WHERE id='$i'"

Also, here is a link to SQL injection, which might give you some information you do not already have: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the code on the page in this order:

`SELECT` query first to get the number rows as the `UPDATE` query needs this information.
`UPDATE` query
`SELECT` query `($result=mysql_query($sql);)` again to update the page data otherwise the page will only show the pre-updated data.

Not very clean but it works...

I note the code originates from the [PHPEasystep.com](http://PHPEasystep.com) website.